# What is an alternative to using RelativeSource Self?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin Forms, I am not sure what the best alternative is for using RelativeSource Self.

For example, if I wanted a label to bind to its own Text or Tag property then in WPF I could do this:

```
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Text">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TextConverter}">
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Tag" />
                    <Binding ElementName="Window" Path="DataContext.SelectedContent" />
                    <Binding ElementName="Window" Path="DataContext.CopyMade" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

What is the best alternative for using Xamarin.Forms?

Answer (score 1):

`RelativeSource` is not supported in `Xamarin.Forms` and the usual alternative is to use `Source={x:Reference}` markup extension.

Depending on wether or not your Style is defined as a Resource in a `ResourceDictionary`, and thus can be reused, you might or might not be able to use `{x:Reference}` as an alternative.